# Can AWK array be used to get largest cluster in correlation matrix?

Tags: matrix, awk

I have a matrix that describes correlation between items A-K, where 1=correlated and 0=uncorrelated.

Is there an easy way to extract the largest cluster from the data? In other words, the cluster with the most correlated elements. Below is some sample data:

```
#  A B C D E F G H I J K
A  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
B  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
C  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
D  1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1
E  1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
F  1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
G  1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
H  1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
I  1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
J  1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
K  1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
```

Swapping a few columns/rows by eye, the expected result would be the top left of the matrix, which is a cluster of size 6 that contains: {A, B, C, D, F, K}

[image]

I know awk isn't the most user-friendly for this application, but I'm keen on using awk since this will integrate into a larger awk script. That being said, I'm not completely immovable on the language.

Not sure where to start but here's a more complex version of what I'm thinking in python:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138325/clustering-a-correlation-matrix

Comment: I'm sure it can be done, but also that Awk is an awkward tool choice for this particular task. What have you searched for, what have you tried, and why are you interested in an Awk solution specifically?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by overlap here anyway; can you link to a relevant explanation? You mean the ones with the smallest number of zeros in them?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @tripleee! I've edited the question to give more detail.

Comment: Can you elaborate about the rows/cols swapping rule? I still don't get why the
`D` row/col can make 6 consecutive `1`s and `H` row/col can't.

Comment: Thanks @tshiono, I currently am doing row/column swaps arbitrarily. In this case you are correct that {A B C H E I} is another set of 6. Ultimately, I might use values for each element that are real numbers (rather than just 0 and 1), and in the case of multiple clusters with the same number of members, the cluster with the lowest sum of its elements will be the optimal cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- all matrices are `symmetric` (ie, square; equal to its transpose; matrix[x,y]=matrix[y,x])
- `matrix[x,x]=1` for all `x`
- all matrix entries are `0` or `1`
- not interested in 1-element clusters
- not interested in permutations of the same cluster (ie, `A,B` is the same as `B,A`)
- since we don't have to worry about permutations we can focus on processing elements in the order in which they show up in the matrix (eg, we process `A,B,C` and ignore the equivalents of `A,C,B`, `B,A,C`, `B,C,A`, `C,A,B` and `C,B,A`); this allows us to focus on processing just the top/right half of the matrix (above the identity/diagonal) and in order from left to right; this will greatly reduce the number of permutations we need to evaluate
- as demonstrated in the question, elements that make up a cluster can be shifted up/left in the matrix so as to fill the top/left of the matrix with `1's` (this comes into play during processing where for each new element we merely need to test the equivalent of the new column/row added to this top/left portion of the matrix)

Regarding the last assumption ... assume we have cluster `A,D` and we now want to test `A,D,F`; we just need to test the new column/row entries (`?`):

```
Current Cluster     New Cluster ?

  A D                 A D F
A 1 1               A 1 1 ?     # if matrix is symmetric then only need to test
D 1 1               D 1 1 ?     # the new column *OR* the new row, not both;
                    F ? ? 1     # bottom/right == 1 == matrix[F,F] per earlier assumption
```

One idea using a recursive function and two `GNU awk's` features: *a)* array of arrays (aka, multi-dimensional arrays) and *b)* `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` for custom sorting of clusters to stdout:

```
awk '

######
# load matrix into memory

FNR==1 { n=(NF-1)                                            # number of elements to be processed
         for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)
             label[i-1]=$i                                   # save labels
         next
       }
       { for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)
             m[FNR-1][i-1]=$i                                # populate matrix array m[row#][column#]
       }

######
# define our recursive function

function find_cluster(cluster, i, clstrcount, stackseq,    j, k, corrcount) {

    # cluster       : current working cluster (eg, "A,B,C")
    # i             : index of latest element (eg, for "A,B,C" => latest element is "C" so i = 3
    # clstrcount    : number of elements in current cluster
    # stackseq      : sequence number of stack[] array
    #               : stack[] contains list of indexes for current cluster (for "A,B,C" stack = "1,2,3")
    # j,k,corrcount : declaring additional variables as "local" to this invocation of the function

    clstrcount++                                             # number of elements to be processed at this call/level

    for (j=i+1;j<=n;j++) {                                   # process all elements/indexes greater than i

        corrcount=1                                          # reset correlation count; always start with 1 since m[j][j]=1

        # check the new column/row added to the top/left of the matrix to see if it extends the current cluster (ie, all entries are "1")

        for (k in stack) {                                   # loop through element/indexes in stack
            if (m[stack[k]][j])                              # check column entries
               corrcount++
            if (m[j][stack[k]])                              # check row entries; not necessary if matrix is symmetric but we will add it here to show the m[][] references
               corrcount++
        }

        if (corrcount == (stackseq*2 +1) ) {                 # if we have all "1"s we have a new cluster of size clstrcount

           stack[++stackseq]=j                               # "push" current element/index on stack; increment stack seq/index
           cluster=cluster "," label[j]                      # add current element/label to cluster

           max= (clstrcount>max) ? clstrcount : max          # new max(cluster count) ?
           clusters[clstrcount][++clsterseq]=cluster         # add new cluster to our master list: clusters[cluster_count][seq]

           find_cluster(cluster, j, clstrcount, stackseq)    # recursive call to check for next element(s)

           delete stack[stackseq--]                          # back from recursive call so "pop" curent element (j) from stack
           gsub(/[,][^,]+$/,"",cluster)                      # remove current element/label from cluster to make way for next element/label to be tested
        }
    }
}

######
# start looking for clusters of size 2+

END    { max=2                                               # not interested in clusters of "1"
         for (i=1;i<n;i++) {                                 # loop through list of elements
             clstrcount=1                                    # init cluster count = 1
             clstrseq=0                                      # init clusters[...][seq] sequence seed
             cluster=label[i]                                # reset cluster to current element/label
             stackseq=1                                      # reset stack[seq] sequence seed
             stack[stackseq]=i                               # "push" current element on stack

             find_cluster(cluster, i, clstrcount, stackseq)  # start recursive calls looking for next element in cluster
         }

######
# for now just display clusters with size > 2; adjust this next line to add/remove cluster sizes from stdout

         if (max>2)                                          # print list of clusters with length > 2
            for (i=max;i>2;i--) {                            # print from largest to smallest and ...
                PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc"         # in alphabetical order
                printf "####### clusters of size %s:\n", i
                for (j in clusters[i])                       # loop through all entries for clusters of size "i"
                    print clusters[i][j]
            }
       }
' matrix.dat
```

**NOTE:** The current version is (admittedly) a bit verbose ... the results of jotting down a first-pass solution as I was working through the details; with some further analysis it may be possible to reduce the code; having said that, the time it takes to find all 2+ sized clusters in this 11-element matrix isn't too bad:

```
real    0m0.084s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.046s
```

This generates:

```
####### clusters of size 6:
A,B,C,D,F,K
A,B,C,E,H,I
####### clusters of size 5:
A,B,C,D,F
A,B,C,D,J
A,B,C,D,K
A,B,C,E,H
A,B,C,E,I
A,B,C,F,I
A,B,C,F,K
A,B,C,H,I
A,B,C,H,J
A,B,C,H,K
A,B,D,F,K
A,B,E,H,I
A,C,D,F,K
A,C,E,H,I
B,C,D,F,K
B,C,E,H,I
####### clusters of size 4:
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,E
A,B,C,F
A,B,C,G
A,B,C,H
A,B,C,I
A,B,C,J
A,B,C,K
A,B,D,F
A,B,D,J
A,B,D,K
A,B,E,H
A,B,E,I
A,B,F,I
A,B,F,K
A,B,H,I
A,B,H,J
A,B,H,K
A,C,D,F
A,C,D,J
A,C,D,K
A,C,E,H
A,C,E,I
A,C,F,I
A,C,F,K
A,C,H,I
A,C,H,J
A,C,H,K
A,D,F,K
A,E,H,I
B,C,D,F
B,C,D,J
B,C,D,K
B,C,E,H
B,C,E,I
B,C,F,I
B,C,F,K
B,C,H,I
B,C,H,J
B,C,H,K
B,D,F,K
B,E,H,I
C,D,F,K
C,E,H,I
####### clusters of size 3:
A,B,C
A,B,D
A,B,E
A,B,F
A,B,G
A,B,H
A,B,I
A,B,J
A,B,K
A,C,D
A,C,E
A,C,F
A,C,G
A,C,H
A,C,I
A,C,J
A,C,K
A,D,F
A,D,J
A,D,K
A,E,H
A,E,I
A,F,I
A,F,K
A,H,I
A,H,J
A,H,K
B,C,D
B,C,E
B,C,F
B,C,G
B,C,H
B,C,I
B,C,J
B,C,K
B,D,F
B,D,J
B,D,K
B,E,H
B,E,I
B,F,I
B,F,K
B,H,I
B,H,J
B,H,K
C,D,F
C,D,J
C,D,K
C,E,H
C,E,I
C,F,I
C,F,K
C,H,I
C,H,J
C,H,K
D,F,K
E,H,I
```

Comment: This is really fantastic @markp-fuso! Works really well! Thank you so much!